# How to forbid the Redirection when the url contains the folder name under the `build` folder of Frontend project?

Tags: security, web, tomcat, redirect

I have a WEB application. When I try to access:

- https://{myDomain.com}//example.com/..;/assets

The browser will bring me to another domain:

- example.com/..;/assets

After my research, i found there are 2 points which result in the Redirection...
The first one is **//{anotherDomain}**, it must be **double-slash**, which means:

- https://{mydomain.com}//example.com/..;/assets # The Redirection happens...
- https://{mydomain.com}/example.com/..;/assets  # The Redirection won't happen...

The second one is the last path of the link must **completely match with the names of the folders under the `build` folder of my Frontend project**. [(i shared the folders under the `build` folder of my frontend project in this screenshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuajk.png)). This means:

- https://{mydomain.com}//example.com/..;/assets # The Redirection happens...
- https://{mydomain.com}//example.com/..;/static # The Redirection happens...
- https://{mydomain.com}//example.com/..;/abc # The Redirection won't happen...

I want to forbid this redirection... thanks a lot!